# Create an Oracle function that returns a table

Tags: plsql, oracle10g, package

I'm trying to create a function in package that returns a table.  I hope to call the function once in the package, but be able to re-use its data mulitple times.  While I know I create temp tables in Oracle, I was hoping to keep things DRY.

So far, this is what I have:

Header:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE TEST AS 

    TYPE MEASURE_RECORD IS RECORD (
      L4_ID VARCHAR2(50),
      L6_ID VARCHAR2(50),
      L8_ID VARCHAR2(50),
      YEAR NUMBER,
      PERIOD NUMBER,
      VALUE NUMBER
    );

    TYPE MEASURE_TABLE IS TABLE OF MEASURE_RECORD;

    FUNCTION GET_UPS(
      TIMESPAN_IN IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'MONTLHY',
      STARTING_DATE_IN DATE,
      ENDING_DATE_IN DATE  
    ) RETURN MEASURE_TABLE;

END TEST;
```

Body:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY TEST AS 

  FUNCTION GET_UPS (
    TIMESPAN_IN IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'MONTLHY',
    STARTING_DATE_IN DATE,
    ENDING_DATE_IN DATE
  ) RETURN MEASURE_TABLE IS

    T MEASURE_TABLE;

  BEGIN

        SELECT  ...
        INTO    T
        FROM    ...

      ;

  RETURN T;

  END GET_UPS;

END TEST;
```

The header compiles, the body does not.  One error message is 'not enough values', which probably means that I should be selecting into the MEASURE_RECORD, rather than the MEASURE_TABLE.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I think you want a [pipelined table function](http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_pipe_functions.html).

Something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE test AS

    TYPE measure_record IS RECORD(
       l4_id VARCHAR2(50), 
       l6_id VARCHAR2(50), 
       l8_id VARCHAR2(50), 
       year NUMBER, 
       period NUMBER,
       VALUE NUMBER);

    TYPE measure_table IS TABLE OF measure_record;

    FUNCTION get_ups(foo NUMBER)
        RETURN measure_table
        PIPELINED;
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY test AS

    FUNCTION get_ups(foo number)
        RETURN measure_table
        PIPELINED IS

        rec            measure_record;

    BEGIN
        SELECT 'foo', 'bar', 'baz', 2010, 5, 13
          INTO rec
          FROM DUAL;

        -- you would usually have a cursor and a loop here   
        PIPE ROW (rec);

        RETURN;
    END get_ups;
END;
```

For simplicity I removed your parameters and didn't implement a loop in the function, but you can see the principle.

Usage:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table(test.get_ups(0));



L4_ID L6_ID L8_ID       YEAR     PERIOD      VALUE
----- ----- ----- ---------- ---------- ----------
foo   bar   baz         2010          5         13
1 row selected.
```

Comment: I'm assuming that using a cursor is going to be more resource-intensive (i.e. slower) than using a temporary table.  Am I correct?

I need to group the results of this function.  Does that alter your recommendation?

Comment: Regarding the cursor, yes I believe they aren't very good for performance so it would probably faster to do a BULK COLLECT as Tony mentioned, and then iterate over the array. It would depend on the number of rows you're dealing with and other performance considerations. As for grouping the results, I'm not sure, but it does seem likely that a temporary table would be more efficient than a pipelined function in any case. I would suggest more research (or better still, experimenting). I'd ask the question at http://asktom.oracle.com.

Comment: "
SELECT *
  FROM table(test.get_ups(0));
"

Thank you SO much! This really helped, I had a function which returns a table and when I executed only "Select my_package.function from dual;" it returned some object that I did not know how to use at all

Comment: @IgbyLargeman  Nice example, any example for return multiple row?

Answer (score 8):

To return the whole table at once you could change the SELECT to:

```
SELECT  ...
BULK COLLECT INTO T
FROM    ...
```

This is only advisable for results that aren't excessively large, since they all have to be accumulated in memory before being returned; otherwise consider the pipelined function as suggested by Charles, or returning a REF CURSOR.

Answer (score 1):

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY TEST AS 

   FUNCTION GET_UPS(
   TIMESPAN_IN IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'MONTLHY',
   STARTING_DATE_IN DATE,
   ENDING_DATE_IN DATE
   )RETURN MEASURE_TABLE IS

    T MEASURE_TABLE;

 BEGIN

    **SELECT   MEASURE_RECORD(L4_ID , L6_ID ,L8_ID ,YEAR ,
             PERIOD,VALUE )  BULK COLLECT  INTO    T
    FROM    ...**

  ;

   RETURN T;

   END GET_UPS;

END TEST;
```

Comment: What's the syntax to call this function?  `select  * from TABLE(TEST.GET_UPS(...))`?