# To get data from Stored Procedure having without parameter

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a stored procedure `proc1` without parameters. I want to extract data from this stored procedure. How can I get that? Could you help me?

Stored procedure:

```
create procedure proc1 
as
begin
    select e_id, e_nm, e_sal 
    from emp 
    where e_id like 'e%';
end proc1;
```

Comment: You should be more specific - to get some answers...  what is the purpose of the procedure?  are you the one writing the stored procedure? what kind of data are you trying to extract?

Comment: @Plirkee in this procedure some SQL statement is there but without parameter. How can i get or extract data from this store procedure or how can i get data from store procedure having parameter

Comment: It will not be fruitful to discuss this without you posting your procedure code in your question.

Comment: @Shahin post the code and explain what do you want to extract (desired output)... Otherwise I doubt that you will get any useful answers.

Comment: it looks like you're trying to port something from MS SQL. Oracle's concepts are different. You should read about cursors first.

Comment: You cannot get data out of a procedure without having parameters. You could either return a cursor as an out parameter, or return some scalar values as an out parameter, but at the end you need parameters.

Comment: The sample code won't compile because a plain `select` needs an `into` to put the results in. You need to define it as a ref cursor. See my reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one possible solution:

**Declaration:**

```
create procedure proc1 (emp_row IN OUT emp%rowtype)
as
begin
  select * --e_id, e_nm, e_sal
    into emp_row
    from emp
   where e_id like 'e%';
end proc1;
```

**Use case:**

```
DECLARE
  l_emp_row emp%rowtype;
BEGIN
  proc1(l_emp_row);
  -- Here you can access every column of table "emp", like so:
    -- dbms_output.put_line('e_id:  ' || to_char(l_emp_row.e_id));
    -- dbms_output.put_line('e_nm:  ' || to_char(l_emp_row.e_nm));
    -- dbms_output.put_line('e_sal: ' || to_char(l_emp_row.e_sal));
END;
```

Is there anything special that you need to get out of the Procedure?

Cheers

Comment: Looks like that has a parameter ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in Oracle 12.1 or above:

```
create or replace procedure demo
as
    rc sys_refcursor;
begin
    open rc for select * from dual;
    dbms_sql.return_result(rc);
end demo;
```

This requires an Oracle 12.1 or later client/driver to handle the implicit result set.

For more details, see Implicit Result Sets in the [Oracle 12.1 New Features Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NEWFT/chapter12101.htm#FEATURENO10020), [Tom Kyte's Blog](http://tkyte.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/12c-implicit-result-sets.html), [Oracle Base](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/implicit-statement-results-12cr1) etc.

Answer (score 0):

1. you create a view this query. (recomended)
2. Oracle procedure is not return any data. So, you do not see any result. Your result get buffer but not print screen. if You need a procedure, insert all data another table.

   ```
   create procedure proc1 
   as
   begin
   insert into new_table select e_id, e_nm, e_sal from emp where e_id like 'e%';
   end proc1;
   ```

Another way; You create a function. Because function outputs and inputs. This function;

for example [Create an Oracle function that returns a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829880/create-an-oracle-function-that-returns-a-table)