# Is there way to use table of varchar 2 in select statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a stored function which returns table of varchar2.
And I want to use it in select

stored function :-

```
create or replace PACKAGE TESTSTR AS 

 TYPE strings_t IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 (4000);

FUNCTION strings
   RETURN strings_t; 

END TESTSTR;

select * from  TABLE (TESTSTR.strings())
```

it is throwing me invalid data type error

> ORA-00902: invalid datatype

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create an Oracle function that returns a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829880/create-an-oracle-function-that-returns-a-table)

Comment: You may want to use a `PIPLELINED TABLE` function as in the linked answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use your list outside of PL/SQL, as in your post, you need to define an `OBJECT` type in the database.  E.g.,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE my_string AS OBJECT (val varchar2(4000));
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE my_string_t AS TABLE OF my_string;
```

... and then use `my_string_t` in place of your PL/SQL `strings_t` type.

As long as your list of strings has fewer than 32768 elements, you can use the pre-defined `SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST` object type instead, saving you the need to declare any new object types.

E.g.,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE teststr AS
  FUNCTION strings RETURN sys.odcivarchar2list;
END teststr;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY teststr AS
  FUNCTION strings RETURN sys.odcivarchar2list IS
    l_list sys.odcivarchar2list;
  BEGIN
    SELECT rownum 
    BULK COLLECT INTO l_list
    FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 1000;

    RETURN l_list;
  END strings;
END teststr;

SELECT * FROM table(teststr.strings);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create function with below option like
    function strings
    return  string_t
    pipelined is
    --declare your type variable as empty
    begin
    --put your logic here
    pipe row(out_variable);
    exception
    --if any
    end;

get out out by using query:
    select * from table(tester.strings);